# Replace spaces with new line in makefile

Tags: string, makefile

Does anyone know how to replace all spaces in a string in to a new line in a Makefile(GNU make)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
text := hello a b c

null :=
space := ${null} ${null}
${space} := ${space}# ${ } is a space. Neat huh?

define \n


endef

$(error [$(subst ${ },${\n},${text})])
```

Comment: Are you sure its ${ } in the last line

Comment: Yes, I defined this macro in line 5. `${space}` and `${ }` both work fine here.

Comment: Sorry...it seems to work when i copy your code exact, but not when i hand-type it....need to chekc from my side

Comment: Can you tell me what are the square brackets for?

Comment: i simply need to echo the output to a file, but if use echo, it doesnt work.

Comment: When printing out the values of variables, I like to see whether they are empty (`[]`), or have leading/trailing spaces (`[Hello world  ]`), or even embedded newlines.

Comment: When are you writing to the file? During initial makefile parsing, or when make is running the commands in a recipe?

Comment: Thanks i got it done. I was using echo to write to a file. Need to use echo -e instead. Thanks

Comment: Extraordinary... That's a really neat trick. The challenge is to bookmark this answer so that it's accessible over multiple devices. :D

Answer (score 6):

It's probably easier -- and cleaner -- to use GNU Make's `shell` function with `sed` to do the replacement, rather than trying to do it entirely within `make`.

```
STRING := foo bar baz
SPLIT  := $(shell echo "${STRING}" | sed -e 's/ /\n/g')
```

Or, slightly better, if your shell is `bash` instead of the default `sh`:

```
STRING := foo bar baz
SPLIT  := $(shell sed -e 's/ /\n/g' <<< ${STRING})
```

Comment: The only problem I find with this is that it still uses shell commands meaning that it complies with ARG_MAX which was my problem in first place. But that's a good solution to other problems I had. Thanks

Comment: Besides `$(shell)` being bad style, **this does not work**! 1: `<<<` only works in _bash_, and by default _make_ uses _sh_. 2: There is a syntax error — `${STRING}` needs to be quoted for the here string to work (`<<<'${STRING}'`). 3: _make_'s `$(shell …)` always replaces newlines with spaces anyway